# Why is there a gap between image and top of screen in my android app?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

in my xml file i am using this. My question is why do I get such a huge gap between top of screen and image when using it on a smaller screen. On a huge screen however everything is fine.

EDIT: I think the problem is because of the weight. Any ideas?

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/area"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/area_selector" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/volume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/volume_selector" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to the imageview tags.

Comment: Worked perfectly!! thank you so much!

Comment: Add the answer and validate it in order to close this question please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Teovalds behalf, the commented answer as an answer:
Try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to the imageview tags.

Answer (score 1):

Also the added magintop = 10 dp can be removed to minimize the gap !